# Iterate through Time Series data from .txt file using Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My background is VBA and very new to Python, so please forgive me at the outset.

I have a .txt file with time series data.

[image]

My goal is to loop through the data and do simple comparisons, such as `High - Close` etc. From a VBA background this is straight forward for me in VBA, namely (in simple terms):

```vb
Sub Loop()

    Dim arrTS() As Variant, i As Long

    arrTS = Array("Date", "Time", ..)

    For i = LBound(arrTS, 1) to UBound(arrTS, 1)
        Debug.Print arrTS(i, "High") - arrTS(i, "Close")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Now what I have in python is:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load the .txt file
ES_D1 = np.loadtxt(fname = os.getcwd()+"\ES\D1\ES_10122007_04122019_D1.txt", dtype='str')

#now get the shape
print(ES_D1.shape)

Out: (3025, 8)
```

Can anyone recommend the best way to iterate through this file line by line, with reference to specific columns, and not iterate through each element?

Something like:

```py
For i = 0 To 3025
   print(ES_D1[i,4] - ES_D1[i,5])
Next i
```

Comment: Good to see a VBA-er picking up Python :-)

Comment: @BigBen thanks, I am sure you will be seeing many more silly questions like this as I learn the new language! ;)

Comment: Not silly, lol. Python is the best, but like you I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the simple for loop was easier than I though, here for others.

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import urllib.requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load the .txt file
ES_D1 = np.loadtxt(fname = os.getcwd()+"\ES\D1\ES_10122007_04122019_D1.txt", dtype='str')

#now need to loop through the array
#this is the engine
for i in range(ES_D1.shape[0]):
    if ES_D1[i,3] > ES_D1[i,6]:
        print(ES_D1[i,0])
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular way to read csv/tsv files for me is this:

```py
import os

filename = '...'
filepath = '...'
infile = os.path.join(filepath, filename)

with open(infile) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        parts = line.split('\t')
        # do something with the list "parts"
```

But in your case, using the pandas function `read_csv()`might be a better way:

```py
import pandas as pd 

# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv
data = pd.read_csv(infile)

# View the first 5 lines
data.head()
```

Comment: +1 for the different approaches, and thanks for the suggestions. Managed to solve the simple issue after posting though.